# Parser library that can handle ambiguity

Tags: parsing, scala, haskell

I'm looking for a mature parser library, either for Scala or Haskell.
The most important point is, that the library can handle ambiguity. 
If an expression is ambiguous, I want every possible abstract syntax tree, that matches the expression.
Simple example: The expression **a ⊗ b ⊗ c** can be seen as **(a ⊗ b) ⊗ c** or **a ⊗ (b ⊗ c)**, and I need both variants. 
Thanks!

Comment: That's going to be a tall order, I guess. The parser generators I played around with (supporting some amount of ambiguity) all simply created a single parse/AST. Usually the first parse that succeeded. Also, given a large enough input source (and an ambiguous grammar), there will going to be huge amounts of possible parses...

Comment: You could use a library like parsec and parse to `[AST]` rather than just `AST`. Obviously this means that you have to write all the different options for the ambiguities by hand, and manage the merging of subresults at each level. But there's probably something you can do with `ParsecT` and the fact that it's a monad transformer to simplify matters slightly. (That's just a guess though, it requires someone more knowledgeable than me.)

Comment: @schlicht I don't know what you understand as "mature", but a minimal parser libray that generates all possible results for any particular expression can be written in like 30 lines of haskell. I know that because that was the first Monad I've written following some article I can't find right now.

Comment: Cubic:  it's safe to say that such a library would not count as mature.  Clearly there are numerous reasons to use a mature library if one exists.

Comment: Happy's GLR parsing should handle ambiguity (that is the selling point of GLR). Happy is a Haskell preprocessor rather than a library, also the GLR support seems rather undercooked compared to the "regular" Happy.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will have a look at every suggestion and see what fits my need. Performance will be an issue, but that I can only really test after I have worked on it for a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end the the choice fell on the Syntax Definition Formalism ([SDF2](http://www.syntax-definition.org/))
with an sdf table generator [here](http://www.syntax-definition.org/Sdf/SdfSoftware)
and [JSGLR](http://strategoxt.org/Stratego/JSGLR/) as parser generator.

Comment: No, thats new for me. Looks good on first glance. But the packages first version is from 2015 and the question from 2012.

Answer (score 13):

I feel like the old guy for remembering when Walder's papers like Comprehending Monads (the precursor to the do notation) were exciting and new. The idea is that you (to quote) replace a failure by a list of successes, meaning maintain a list of all the possible parses. At the end you normally just take the first match, but with this setup, you can take all of them.

These aren't all that efficient for a deterministic parser, which is why they're less in fashion, but they are what you need.

Have a look at [polyparse](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Polyparse), and in particular `Text.ParserCombinators.HuttonMeijer` and `Text.ParserCombinators.HuttonMeijerWallace`.

(Hutton & Meijer translated the parser library to Haskell (from Gofer) and Wallace added extra features.)

Make sure you check it out on simple cases like parsing `"aaaa"` with

```
testP = do
   a <- many $ char 'a'
   b <- many $ char 'a'
   return (a,b)
```

to see if it has the semantics you seek.

You asked for mature. These libraries are part of pure functional programming's heritage! Having said that, I'd call parsec more mature, even though it's younger.

(Speculation: I don't think parsec can do what you want. Its standard choice combinator is deterministic. I haven't looked into tweaking or replacing that behaviour, and I wouldn't want to I'm afraid.)

Answer (score 4):

This question immediately reminded me of the [Yacc is dead](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5023) / [No, it's not](http://research.swtch.com/yaccalive) debate from the end of 2010. The authors of the *Yacc is dead* paper provide a [library](http://www.ucombinator.org/projects/parsing/) in Scala (unmaintained),  Haskell and Racket. In the *Yacc is alive* response, Russ Cox points out that the code runs in exponential time for ambiguous grammars.

It's well-known that it is possible to parse ambiguous grammars in `O(n^3)`, although obviously it can take exponential time to enumerate all the parse trees in the case that there are exponentially many of them -- and there will be in the case of `x1 + x2 + x3 ... + xn`. `bison` implements the GLR algorithm which does so; unfortunately, while `bison` is certainly mature (if not actually moribund), it is written neither in Haskell nor in Scala.

Daniel Spiewak implemented a GLL parser in Scala IIRC, but last time I looked at it, it suffered from some performance issues. So I'm not sure that it could be described as mature, either.

Comment: Preco (the company that Daniel and I work for) uses GLL heavily. Our product is very performance critical and GLL keeps up with it in both performance and maturity.

Comment: Russ Cox's exponential time example is wrong, but other much less natural ones do exist.

Comment: Does Bison really handles syntactic ambiguity?

Comment: @sergey: bison's GLR implementation insists that ambiguity be resolved but is flexible about how; one possibility is creating a parse forest. So in a sense, it can handle ambiguity, but it is not very good at exponential ambiguity because it does not implement a graph structured stack.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to how mature it is or give you any usage examples, but I've had the scala [gll-combinators](https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators) library open in a tab for a few days. It handles ambiguous grammars and looks pretty nifty.